# Converting First order logic to CNF

Tags: programming-languages, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, markov-chains

Is there a existing implementation in C/c++/java to convert first order logic to CNF ?

Answer (score 1):

It might be more efficient to use something like: [Boolean Normal Form](http://code.google.com/p/moses/wiki/BooleanNormalForm)

For implementation, I recommend doing it yourself for something simple like this. An efficient method has psuedo code + explanation [here](http://research.yahoo.com/files/EvaluatingComplexBooleanExpressions.pdf)